# Join with gzipped files

Tags: linux, gzip, join

I want to use the command line join utility on two files.  Unfortunately, they're gzipped.  Because they're both gzipped, I can't use gzip -cd.  Is there a slick way to do this without having to unzip them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but bash (among other shells) can do process substitution.

```
join <(zcat foo.gz) <(zcat bar.gz)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is documented in man page of gzip. You can use something like:

```
zcat a.gz b.gz | gzip -c > c.txt.gz
```